# Установка Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

При установке Ruby on rails наткнулся на небольшую проблему. 
Действовал так же, как описано в туториале на http://railstutorial.ru/.
После выполнения `gem install rails --version 4.0.0` 
попытался запустить `rails -v` и получил ошибку:

```
Приложение 'rails' может быть найдено в следующих пакетах:
 * rails
 * ruby-railties-3.2
Попробуйте: sudo apt-get install <выбранный пакет>
```

Гуглением понял, что необходимо добавить путь до gem:

```
PATH="${PATH}:~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576@railstutorial_rails_4_0/bin/"
```

Снова попробовал запустить `rails -v` с тем же результатом.  
После чего заметил, что рельсы установились по странному пути, а именно `~/o-ri/`.
Перешел туда и запустил напрямую `./rails -v`, чем получил ожидаемый результат:

```
Rails 4.1.6
```

Казалось бы, вот и решение, но пятая точка подсказывает, что не все так хорошо.
Подскажите, какие проблемы возникнут и как их избежать? Или, может, я накосячил на каком-то из этапов, и надо все переделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы неправильно установили RVM. А возможно, просто забыли перезапустить терминал после установки. Так или иначе, bash не пытается искать команды в директориях гемов RVM.

Попробуйте установить его заново и проследите, что необходимые для его работы строчки добавились (в `~/.bashrc`, по-моему, но, может, и в `~/.profile`).